# Kubernetes and gcloud: how to stop using service account?

Tags: permissions, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-cloud-storage

I work with a number of Google Cloud Services. Some of the Cloud Storage buckets where I work are in project-A, which is accessible from my own account, and some are in project-B, which I can only access with a service account. I activated the appropriate service account with

`gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file mykey.json`

During subsequent logins I just used

`gcloud config set account service_account`

I also needed to switch my active project, for which I used the command

`gcloud config set project project-B`

The service account worked perfectly well, allowing me to access a particular bitbucket stored on Google Cloud Storage, but afterward I needed to use Argo to submit a kubernetes workflow, so I switched back to my account and project with the commands

```
gcloud config set account my_account
gcloud config set project project-A
```

Using "gcloud auth list" I can see that my_account is active

```
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
        service_account.iam.gserviceaccount.com
*       my_account
```

But I got the following error when I tried submitting running "kubectl -n default get services":

```
Error from server (Forbidden): services is forbidden: User "service_account.iam.gserviceaccount.com" cannot list resource "services" in API group "" in the namespace "default": Required "container.services.list" permission.
```

I get the same error when I use my_namespace rather than default. I'm rather confused by this because gcloud commands like "gsutil ls" function as though I'm in the correct account and project. Why does kubernetes still think I'm using a service account, and how do I make it stop using it so I can do what I need to with kubernetes again? The commands and pipelines I'm trying to run worked perfectly fine before activating the service account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out I just needed to run

`gcloud container clusters get-credentials mycluster`

Initially, I thought that I would also need to fix this by deleting my kubeconfig file at
`~/.kube/config`
then running the get-credentials command, but as pointed out in the comments it turns out that the get-credentials command was all that was necessary.

The problem appears to specifically surface from running argo commands while the gcloud service account is active: the command would first fail, then all subsequent kubectl commands would return this permissions error. If I switched into the service account, ran the gcloud commands, then switched back into my account, it would not affect kubectl's behavior.

Comment: I didn't have to remove the kubeconfig file but running `gcloud container clusters get-credentials ...` fixed this for me.  I happened to run some tests that use a service account, and I didn't switch back to my one before running `kubectl get pods` and it got things into a broken state.  This had me puzzled for a while, thanks very much for coming back with the answer :)

Comment: Good point on that; I ran into this issue again and verified that my problem was also solved by the get-credentials command without deleting the .kube/config file. I've changed the answer to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: Then you should accept your own answer too :) (because it just got me out of trouble again...)